# R how to make asynchronous(or)synchronization requests?

Tags: r

My R program produced a dataframe1 and write it into databaseA(eg.oracle database),but another databaseB(eg.MySQL) want this dataframe1,
How do I synchronization databaseA's dataframe1 to MySQL databaseB using the URL from databaseB? Do I need to make asynchronous requests using any R packages?
my R program on the offline server? Do I have to add the URL to my previous R program？

databaseB's URL:http://10.234.200.173:8088/Server/data/forecast/synchronize?kpi_no=$kpi_id, which offered by my other department colleague.

Comment: Not sure if this is R related. If I understand correctly you're trying to move a part of the table from dbA to dbB, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is a R related problem, your understand definitely correctly. I have to add the URL which from dbB to my R code, But I dont't know how to do that. Do you have any suggestion? thanks